# Exception block not working in DBMS_CLOUD PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, procedure

I'm new on using Oracle products, lately I've been trying to use create_external_table from DBMS_CLOUD package and also I'm intentionally making the function fail. But the expected message is not being thrown, as you can see the complete exception is thrown.

Do you know what could be wrong in my code?

```
SQL> begin
  2  dbms_cloud.create_external_table(
  3  table_name => 'ext_table',
  4  credential_name =>'cred_name',
  5  file_uri_list => 'https://.../invalidBucket/...',
  6  column_list => 'name varchar2(20), age number',
  7  format => json_object('type' value 'CSV'));
  8  exception
  9      when others then
 10              dbms_output.put_line('Failed!');
 11  
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> select * from ext_table order by 1;
select * from ext_table order by 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-20400: Request failed with status HTTP 400 -
https.*
Error response - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidBucketName</Code><Message>The specified bucket is not
valid.</Message><BucketName></BucketName><RequestId>RequestID</RequestId>
<HostId>HostID</HostId></Error>
ORA-06512
ORA-06512
ORA-06512
```

Edit:

I had tried write and exception around the select query, but I only get an message "Procedure succesfully completed"

```
SQL> declare
  2  c_name varchar2(20) := 'a';
  3  begin
  4  select name into c_name from ext_table order by 1;
  5  exception
  6      when others then
  7              dbms_output.put_line('Failed from select');
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: are you in SQLPlus? SQL Developer? something else? you need to run SET SERVEROUTPUT on in order to see DBMS_OUTPUT messages.

Answer (score 1):

The `dbms_cloud.create_external_table` call isn't failing so you'd never enter your exception handler.

The external table is created successfully.  When you query the external table, Oracle makes the HTTP call and you get a runtime error.  You could put an exception handler around the query against the external table which could catch the failure and do something with it.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried that before, and I only get a message "Procedure successfully completed" you can see it detailed in the edit section

Comment: @nicolasdi - I'd guess that you haven't enabled `dbms_output` or that you're not looking at the `dbms_output` window if you're using SQL Developer.  It would be helpful to do something like calling `dbms_output` before your `select` to show that output is actually enabled and printing to the screen.

Comment: Solution: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;